# How to use 2 different REALM files in the same app

Tags: android, realm

I have developed an app with one language "`English`", after while they asked me to add another language, and the structure of the database CAN NOT have the 2 languages in the same DB, so how to implement 2 `realm DBs` files in the same app. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different Realm file using the `name` parameter. Then just choose the right configuration depending on the context

```
RealmConfiguration englishConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("english.realm")
  .build();

RealmConfiguration germanConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("german.realm")
  .build();
```